# How to template data that socket.io sends onto a page?

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I've built a small testbed for socket.io here: https://creativespace.nodejitsu.com/ideas and I've encountered a challenge, each time a new user sends data through socket.io I have to update the page with that new data, I can handle that fine in socket.io, but how do I deal with templating after the fact? I use jade for rendering my pages. Is there any way to use jade again to render new content to the page on the fly? Or do I have to make up a jquery solution?

Any help would rock!

Comment: did you tried using jquery templates?

Comment: Nope, not yet. I've heard of it.

Comment: try templates and embed the html in your page

Comment: Like this? https://tutsplus.com/lesson/each-and-templating/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Comment: Thanks Aby! -silly character minimum-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try jquery templates and embed the html in your page

Use jquery Templates:

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates